# GIGYA error:[facebook] can't login with WebView, install related sdk

Tags: ios, cocoapods, maui, gigya

I started to using the new GigyaSwift SDK and I'm trying to implement facebook social login.
So I have imported the SDK and wrappers in my project, and installed the FBSDK pods.
However I got following error.

> Fatal error: [facebook] can't login with WebView, install related sdk.

I can login with phone number or email account.
I get a similar error message with my Google social login.

> Fatal error: [googleplus] can't login with WebView, install related sdk.

These are the fields I have inputted into my plist.

```
<key>CFBundleURLTypes</key>
<array>
    <dict>
        <key>CFBundleTypeRole</key>
        <string>Editor</string>
        <key>CFBundleURLName</key>
        <string>MyApp</string>
        <key>CFBundleURLSchemes</key>
        <array>
            <string>REDACTED</string>
        </array>
    </dict>
    <dict>
        <key>CFBundleTypeRole</key>
        <string>Editor</string>
        <key>CFBundleURLName</key>
        <string>MyApp</string>
        <key>CFBundleURLSchemes</key>
        <array>
            <string>REDACTED</string>
        </array>
    </dict>
</array>
<key>FacebookAppID</key>
<string>REDACTED</string>
<key>FacebookClientToken</key>
<string>REDACTED</string>
<key>FacebookDisplayName</key>
<string>MyApp ID Login</string>
<key>GoogleClientID</key>
<string>REDACTED</string>
<key>GoogleServerClientID</key>
<string>REDACTED</string>
```

And this is my podfile

```
  pod 'AppAuth', '= 1.5.0', :modular_headers => false
  pod 'GoogleSignIn', '= 6.2.3', :modular_headers => false
  pod 'GTMSessionFetcher', '= 1.7.2', :modular_headers => false
  pod 'FBSDKCoreKit', '= 14.1.0', :modular_headers => false
  pod 'FBSDKLoginKit', '= 14.1.0', :modular_headers => false
  pod 'Gigya', '= 1.3.2', :modular_headers => false
  # Remove signing on Xcode 14
  post_install do |installer|
      installer.generated_projects.each do |target|
          target.build_configurations.each do |config|
            config.build_settings['CODE_SIGNING_ALLOWED'] = "NO"
            config.build_settings['CODE_SIGNING_REQUIRED'] = "NO"
            config.build_settings['EXPANDED_CODE_SIGN_IDENTITY'] = ""
          end
        end
    end
end
```

I'm implementing a .Net MAUI application and I've created a binding library for GIGYA to include in my application.
If anyone knows how to solve this, please let me know.

I checked the application name mentioned in the info.plist and made sure there are no spaces in the name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can only use login with facebook, google, line, or wechat via their own native sdks. this means you need to install the Facebook and Google SDKs into your app if you want the user to be able to use them to login with. https://sap.github.io/gigya-swift-sdk/GigyaSwift/#facebook

Comment: I settled this problem. It couldn't find the FB and Google login classes in GigyaSwift SDK because I didn't set CFBundleName in info.plist.